# Disable color for thor

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

I have a CLI app that uses Thor.

Right now, it uses colors for a lot of output, which looks nice but causes issues with piping to scripts and such.

However, it's going to be a rather large refactor to add options every time I use a color.

Is there an easy way to just ignore all color options in Thor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thor is [smart enough](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/f0c2166534e122636f5ce04d61885736ef605617/lib/thor/shell.rb#L12-L13) to read the env variable:

```
export THOR_SHELL=Basic
```